# Redis for Django-application

Tags: django, web-services, redis

I'm writing eCommerce web-application with Django 1.9.5. 
It will not be any close to highload, it's just a trivial application. 
My question is should I use Redis for following purposes:

- Storing user's sessions (I'm using session mechanism quite a lot)
- Storing logs
- Using with Celery to async tasks (sending emails and so on)

What are pros and cons in these? Should I go with Redis+Celery or simply stick with classical caching backends and synchronous actions in views?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [cacheops](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops) for caching in all my django apps.

It gives build in query caching and invalidation on model updates.

All you need to add caching for all User related queries is to add to your settings.py few lines:

```
CACHEOPS = {
    'auth.user': {'ops': 'get', 'timeout': 60*15},
}
```

I assume you can add session caching in the same way.

If you doesn't expect highload on your project I'm sure it'll be enough.